# Ruby on rails : download route not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, download, zip, production-environment

I have a download function that works fine on my project, the process is to make a folder that contain two pdf files, zip it into the tmp folder and then download it, everything works fine on localhost, when I deployed the branch on production mode I got an error : in fact the process of creation and zip the folder that contain the reports works fine except the download function.

here is the **route.rb** file :

```
get 'reports/:id/download'    => 'reports#download_report', as: "download_report"
```

**DownloadReportHelper**

```
def self.zip_pdf(report, path, current_company)
    if File.exist?(temporary_dir_path(report, current_company)+ ".zip")
      FileUtils.rm(temporary_dir_path(report, current_company)+ ".zip")
    end
    directory = File.join( File.dirname( path ) )
    zipfile_name = File.join( File.dirname( path ) ) + '.zip'
    Zip::ZipFile.open( zipfile_name, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE ) do |zipfile|
      Dir[ File.join( directory, '*' ) ].each do |file|
        zipfile.add( File.basename( file ), file )
      end
    end
  end
```

**ReportsController**:

```
def download_report
    report = Report.find( params[ :id ] ).decorate
    report_pdfs_path = DownloadReportHelper.generate_public_and_internal_pdf( report, current_company )
    DownloadReportHelper.zip_pdf( report, report_pdfs_path, current_company )
    send_file( "#{ File.dirname(report_pdfs_path) }.zip")
    report.update!(last_downloaded_at: DateTime.current)
  end
```

the link structure generated to download report is like that :

```
https://company.domainname.com/reports/c2b4e249-175d-4d92-90e1-a7cac5b329c0/download
```

I got :

> This site can’t be reached

any one can help to find what's wrong with that and why it works fine on localhost but not in production ?

Comment: That error is very ambiguous. Is the issue that your wifi connection stopped working??!! Or is it perhaps a timeout error - so the request did reach the server, but took too long to respond so your browser gave up?

Comment: I suspect it's simply that you're dealing with much more data in production, so the request takes much longer. You may need to make this operation asynchronous - i.e. the action schedules a background job.

Comment: Please provide more info. Do other pages of the site work fine, or you have a problem with the site on prod in general? The error message points that it is a network problem, not a bug in the application. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8P9mZNIf414 how to fix it.

Comment: the app work fine only this download function don't :!

Answer (score 0):

Complex file manipulation, data extraction, reporting etc. in general should not be handled inside of your app controllers directly. You might get away with it locally with a small data set, but in a production environment this surely won't scale and most web servers default timeout around 30-45 seconds. That means if you send an http request to the server, and the server takes longer than the default timeout, it will do just that, timeout and not respond.  The way to handle this is to use background jobs.

Rails provides [ActiveJob](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) and to use it in production, you'll need to select a backend.  Here are some possible choices for that.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

https://github.com/brandonhilkert/sucker_punch